# JungleDisk for Microsoft Azure

Tags: backup, cloud, cloud-storage

Is there something like [JungleDisk](https://jungledisk.com), but based on Microsoft Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet.  Azure is still in Community Preview mode.  It will be moving into production on 1/1/2010.  At that time you should expect to see pay services like JungleDisk go online.

Comment: I know about that, but I expecting some kind of technology preview for application like Azure JungleDisk.

Comment: There hasn't been anything announced at PDC, and none of the vendors hare in the backup or hosting business.  To date, all of the announcements / reference customers are firmly enterprise customer space.

Comment: Microsoft has announced that you can mount blob storage as an NTFS drive, so you may be able to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out Gladinet Cloud Desktop @ http://www.gladinet.com

it allows you to map Azure Blob Storage as network drive/virtual folder, together with Amazon S3, Google Docs and a bunch of other services.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Beta of [Windows Azure Drive](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsazure/archive/2010/02/02/beta-release-of-windows-azure-drive.aspx) which was released on 2 February 2010 which is what Stephen appears to be referencing.